# BottomNavigatorBar vs Tabbar on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tabbar, bottombar, bottom-navigation-bar

I know how can I use tabbar or bottomNavigatorBar. I can create bottom bar with both of them but my question is which one is the best usage to create bottom bar? I mean, which one should I use to create bottom bar?

Comment: One question, is it mobile specific or for all device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be design based, how you prefer. I prefer using `BottomNavigatorBar` for <=5 destination. Else, use with Tabbar sometimes.

Let's check the Google material about [bottom-navigation](https://m2.material.io/components/bottom-navigation#usage)

> Bottom navigation bars display three to five destinations at the bottom of a screen. Each destination is represented by an icon and an optional text label. When a bottom navigation icon is tapped, the user is taken to the top-level navigation destination associated with that icon.

Comment: So, it depends on my usage. I got it my friend. Many Thanks..